# Windows Home server is not detecting Samsung ML-1610 printer

Tags: printer, windows-home-server

Have any ideas why? My Windows Vista box recognizes the printer.

**Update**
 It's connected via usb.

Comment: `Start -> Run -> devmgmt.msc`.  Do you see a yellow "`!`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Samsung ML-1610 printer driver for Vista, found [here](http://www.driversbay.com/drivers/printers/samsung/ml-1610/microsoft-windows-vista/).

Comment: windows home server is based on windows 2003, not vista. And i already tried installing the correct drivers and detection still does not work.

Comment: What's the answer to hyperslug's question?

Comment: Very strange: neither driversbay.com neither nodevice.com list any drivers for this printer on Win2003. Where did you get your drivers?